# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - need help

Tags: java, android

Программа вылетает при нажатии кнопки Расчет. Как я понял, проблема на этапе присвоении результатов расчётов в `setTextView`.

```
public class PressFindHend extends AppCompatActivity {
public static double z_start;
public static double z_end;
public static double length;
public static double h_start;
public static double q;
public static int concentration;
public static int temperature;
public static double V_start;
public static double sdrMAX;
public static double sdrMIN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Присваивание переменных из введенных в поля значений в активити find_h_end
    EditText z_start_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.z_start_input);
    //Избавляемся от пробела и преобразуем введенный текст в дробь
    z_start = Double.parseDouble(z_start_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText z_end_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.z_end_input);
    z_end = Double.parseDouble(z_end_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText length_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.length_input);
    length = Double.parseDouble(length_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText h_start_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.h_end_input);
    h_start = Double.parseDouble(h_start_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText q_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.q_input);
    q = Double.parseDouble(q_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText concentration_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.concentration_input);
    concentration = Integer.parseInt(concentration_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText temperature_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temperature_input);
    temperature = Integer.parseInt(temperature_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText velocity_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.velocity_input);
    V_start = Double.parseDouble(velocity_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText sdrMAX_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sdrMAX_input);
    sdrMAX = Double.parseDouble(sdrMAX_input.getText().toString().trim());

    EditText sdrMIN_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sdrMIN_input);
    sdrMIN = Double.parseDouble(sdrMIN_input.getText().toString().trim());



    //Инициализация переменных выхода
    h_start_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h_start_output_H_end);
    h_end_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h_end_output_H_end);
    z_start_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_start_output_H_end);
    z_end_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_end_output_H_end);
    length_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.length_output_H_end);
    q_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_output_H_end);
    concentration_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.concentration_output_H_end);
    temperature_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature_output_H_end);
    V_real_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.velocity_output_H_end);
    pressureLossPerMeter_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureLossPerMeter_output_H_end);
    pressureLossOnLength_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureLossOnLength_output_H_end);
    pressureLossLocals_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureLossLocals_output_H_end);
    totalLosses_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalLosses_output_H_end);
    externalDiameter_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.externalDiameter_output_H_end);
    sdrMAX_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdrMAX_output_H_end);
    delta_Z_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delta_Z_output_H_end);
}


private static double sdrMAX_temp;
public static double V_real;
public static double pressureLossOnLength;
public static double pressureLossLocals;
public static double delta_Z;
public static double h_end;

//Переменные вывода
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView h_end_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView h_start_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView z_start_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView z_end_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView pressureLossPerMeter_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView pressureLossOnLength_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView pressureLossLocals_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView totalLosses_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView V_real_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView sdrMAX_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView externalDiameter_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView temperature_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView concentration_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView q_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView length_output;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView delta_Z_output;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public static void calculateHReq() throws Exception {
    //Переводим начальный напор в бары
    h_start = h_start / 10.197;
    //Соотносим начальный напор с SDR
    if (h_start <= 4) sdrMAX_temp = 41;
    else if (h_start > 4 && h_start <= 5) sdrMAX_temp = 33;
    else if (h_start > 5 && h_start <= 6.3) sdrMAX_temp = 26;
    else if (h_start > 6.3 && h_start <= 8) sdrMAX_temp = 21;
  

    else if (h_start > 20)
    throw new Exception("Начальный напор превышает максимально возможный для SDR9");

if (sdrMAX >= sdrMAX_temp) sdrMAX = sdrMAX_temp;
// Диаметр "расчетный" предварительный
double d_pre = Math.pow(((q * 4 / 1000) / Math.PI / V_start), 0.5) * 1000;

if (sdrMAX == 41) selectionDiameterSDR41(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 33) selectionDiameterSDR33(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 26) selectionDiameterSDR26(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 21) selectionDiameterSDR21(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 17.6) selectionDiameterSDR17_6(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 17) selectionDiameterSDR17(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 13.6) selectionDiameterSDR13_6(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 11) selectionDiameterSDR11(d_pre);
else if (sdrMAX == 9) selectionDiameterSDR9(d_pre);

V_real = ((4 * q / 1000) / Math.PI) / Math.pow((internalDiameter / 1000), 2);
double lambda = findLambda();
double pressureLossPerMeter = lambda * Math.pow(V_real, 2) / (2 * 9.81 * internalDiameter) * 1000;
pressureLossOnLength = pressureLossPerMeter * length;
pressureLossLocals = pressureLossOnLength * 0.15;
delta_Z = z_end - z_start;
double totalLosses = pressureLossOnLength + pressureLossLocals + delta_Z;
h_end = h_start - totalLosses;

if (h_end < 0) throw new Exception("Конечный напор меньше 0");


`h_start_output.setText(Double.toString(h_start));
h_end_output.setText(Double.toString(h_end));
z_start_output.setText(Double.toString(z_start));
z_end_output.setText(Double.toString(z_end));
delta_Z_output.setText(Double.toString(delta_Z));
length_output.setText(Double.toString(length));
q_output.setText(Double.toString(q));
concentration_output.setText(Double.toString(concentration));
temperature_output.setText(Double.toString(temperature));
V_real_output.setText(Double.toString(V_real));
pressureLossPerMeter_output.setText(Double.toString(pressureLossPerMeter));
pressureLossOnLength_output.setText(Double.toString(pressureLossOnLength));
pressureLossLocals_output.setText(Double.toString(pressureLossLocals));
totalLosses_output.setText(Double.toString(totalLosses));
externalDiameter_output.setText(Double.toString(externalDiameter));
sdrMAX_output.setText(Double.toString(sdrMAX));`
```

}

Ошибка

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prk, PID: 6998
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prk/com.example.prk.PressFindHend}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2073)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.prk.PressFindHend.onCreate(PressFindHend.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3315)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2073) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

Код самой активити

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".PressFindHend">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Результаты расчета"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">
             
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/h_start_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/h_end_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/z_start_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/z_end_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/delta_Z_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/length_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/concentration_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temperature_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/velocity_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pressureLossPerMeter_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pressureLossOnLength_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pressureLossLocals_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalLosses_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/externalDiameter_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sdrMAX_output_H_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что у вашей переменной с типом EditText без значения (там null) был вызван метод `getText`:  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`, а тут говорится, что это  произошло на 32 строчке вашего класса `PressFindHend.java`: `at com.example.prk.PressFindHend.onCreate(PressFindHend.java:32)`

Comment: В `onCreate()` вы ищете кучу `EditText`-ов, а в разметке нет ни одного - это как? Саму разметку вы на экран не ставите (где вызов `setContentView(R.layout.activity_...)`?).  И брать текст из них в `onCreate()` не имеет смысла - вьюшки ещё даже не появились на экране и уж тем более никто в них тексты ещё не вводил (разве что вы сами их задали в xml)

Comment: Потому что данные из EditText получают из другой разметки, в которую вбивается начальные данные расчета. Вкратце механизм программы - на одной разметке вводятся данные, на второй выводятся результаты расчета.

Comment: woesss прав - добавьте setContentView. А лучше перепишите код на нормальный.

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!